# ontouch listner working properly on one image but not working on secpnd image in same activity?

Tags: android

public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener {

```
SimpleSideDrawer mSlidingMenu;

LinearLayout Commercial, residencial, loyalityinfo, postproperty,
        setpropertyalrt, setting, myactivity, postrequirement;

ImageView menu, login, signup;
LinearLayout menulayout;
ImageView logout, leftslide, leftslidee, logo;
TextView my;
String uid, username;

ImageView myreq, rentsale;

TransparentProgressDialog pdialog;

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;

ViewPagerAdptr adapter;
SlidingTabLayut tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = { "My Properties", "My Requirements", "My Favorite" };
int Numboftabs = 3;

LinearLayout tablayout, simplelayout;

String sucess;

ConnectionStatus status;
boolean isConnected;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
double latitude, longitude;
String regId;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    isConnected = status.isConnected();

    if (isConnected) {

    } else {

        if (pdialog.isShowing())
            pdialog.dismiss();
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("ChdProperty");
        alertDialog.setMessage("No Internet Connection Available");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
                dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(dialogIntent);

            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.hide();

    status = new ConnectionStatus(this);

    SharedPreferences acc = getSharedPreferences("account", 1);
    uid = acc.getString("uid", "");
    username = acc.getString("username", "");

    pdialog = new TransparentProgressDialog(this, R.drawable.loader);

    tablayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);

    simplelayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.simplelayout);

    myactivity();

    Log.d("SESSIONACCOUNT", "Username >> " + username);
    Log.d("SESSIONACCOUNT", "Username >> " + username);
    Log.d("SESSIONACCOUNT", "Username >> " + username);

    mSlidingMenu = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);
    mSlidingMenu.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.behind_menu_left);

    residencial = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.residencialmenulayout);
    Commercial = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.commercialmenulayout);

    loyalityinfo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.loyalityinfomenulayout);
    postproperty = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.postpropertymenulayout);
    setpropertyalrt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.propertyalertmenulayout);

    postrequirement = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.postrequirementmenulasgfyout);

    myactivity = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myactivitymenulayout);
    setting = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.settingmenulayout);

    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    login = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonhomelogin);
    signup = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonhomeregister);
    menulayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menulayout);
    menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homemenuimgcom);

    leftslide = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leftslidee);

    leftslidee = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leftslide);

    logout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.buttonlogout);
    my = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewmyname);

    myreq = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewreq);
    rentsale = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewrent);

    if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");

        my.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        logout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        signup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");

    } else {

        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");

        my.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        logout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        my.setText(username);

        login.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        signup.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");

    }

    OnTouchListener touchListener = new OnTouchListener() {

        float previouspoint = 0;
        float startPoint = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.leftslide: // Give your R.id.sample ...
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // startPoint = event.getX();
                    // System.out.println("Action down,..." + event.getX());
                    mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    // mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    previouspoint = event.getX();
                    if (previouspoint > startPoint) {

                        mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
                    } else {
                        mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    leftslide.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    OnTouchListener ThumbTouch = new OnTouchListener() {
        float previouspoint = 0;
        float startPoint = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.leftslide: // Give your R.id.sample ...
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // startPoint = event.getX();
                    // System.out.println("Action down,..." + event.getX());
                    mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                    // mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();

                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    previouspoint = event.getX();
                    if (previouspoint > startPoint) {

                        mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
                    } else {
                        mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    leftslidee.setOnTouchListener(ThumbTouch);


    menulayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mSlidingMenu.toggleDrawer();

        }
    });

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (username.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2null");

        Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, ResidencialActivity.class);
        // i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    } else {

        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");
        Log.d("Sesionif", "equal2value");

        finish();

    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}

public void myactivity() {

    pdialog.show();

    String logou = "http://www.chandigarhpropertyonline.com/api/MyActivityAPI.php?uid=";

    String url = logou + uid;

    Log.d("GetLogouturllll", url);
    Log.d("GetLogouturllll", url);
    Log.d("GetLogouturllll", url);

    Request hh = (Request) new Request(url) {

        @Override
        protected void onComplete(Transport transport) {

            super.onComplete(transport);

            JSONObject jsonobj = transport.getResponseJson();

            Log.d("getprofileresponse", "" + jsonobj);

            try {
                sucess = jsonobj.getString("success");

                // JSONObject use = jsonobj.getJSONObject("user");

                if (pdialog.isShowing()) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();
                }

                if (sucess.equals("1")) {
                    // if (sucess.equals("1")) {

                    tablayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    simplelayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    adapter = new ViewPagerAdptr(
                            getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, Numboftabs);

                    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
                    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

                    tabs = (SlidingTabLayut) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

                    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayut.TabColorizer() {

                        @Override
                        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {

                            return getResources().getColor(
                                    R.color.tabsScrollColor);

                        }
                    });

                    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

                } else {

                    tablayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    simplelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                if (pdialog.isShowing()) {
                    pdialog.dismiss();`
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }.execute("GET");

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

the touch listner on image leftslidee working properly but not woking on image leftslide?  any solution for this issue...

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are on leftslide, one overwrites the other. And both cases are with R.id.leftslide.

Edit:
Oh for love of god, these variable names. Don't mind the first part, just the one about case.

Comment: @GouravSharma please read this article http://codebuild.blogspot.com/2012/02/15-best-practices-of-variable-method.html especially  nr.6, it will help you with a lot of errors in future.